# plone: cancel in jQuery delete_confirmation overlay does not trigger same action as cancel on the delete_confirmation page

Tags: javascript, jquery, overlay, plone

in plone 4.2, i've customised my form and script actions in  /site/portal_form_controller and with a custom action to redirect when you hit the 'cancel' button on the delete_confirmation for certain types of objects.

things work properly if i navigate to the delete confirmation page for the object  /site/object1/delete_confirmation and hit the cancel button, however, when i select delete in the drop down and the jQuery overlay comes up, and i hit cancel, the overlay simply closes without the redirect.

thanks,

dan

Comment: for now i've just commented out the delete_confirmation in the popupform.js in the zmi /portal_skins/plone_ecmascript/manage_main/ i lose delete confirmation overlays for all object types this way - is there a way to control the filter: to work with object types? - now set to common_content_filter

Comment: `$('dl#plone-contentmenu-actions a#delete').prepOverlay(
        {
            subtype: 'ajax',
            filter: common_content_filter,
            formselector: '#delete_confirmation',
            noform: function(el) {return $.plonepopups.noformerrorshow(el, 'redirect');},
            redirect: $.plonepopups.redirectbasehref,
            closeselector: '[name="form.button.Cancel"]',
            width:'50%'
        }
    );`

Comment: additionally, could i use the `onClose` or `close` in the prepOverlay and somehow trigger the same action as the Cancel button?    thanks!!